# error Too large total max_bars_back 309517 max 300000 allowed in Pinescript

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

Have a nice day

I have problem with my max_bars_back in my pinescript code and I couldn't solve it

```
strategy('Test',shorttitle='Test' , overlay=true, pyramiding=10, commission_type=strategy.commission.percent, commission_value=0.01, initial_capital=1000, default_qty_type=strategy.cash, default_qty_value=500, currency=currency.USD, max_bars_back=3000)
```

when I for example put 2900 in max_bars_back it's ok, but I can't put more than that and when I do it gets me this error : "Too large total max_bars_back 309517 max 300000 allowed".

however in Pinescript references says we can put maximum 5000 in max_bars_back

Comment: In most cases there is not any reasons to use the `max_bars_back=***` parameter. Only in some rare cases it needed.

Comment: Hi  Andrey D, thanks for your comment , yes I'm aware of that and in this case I need it